# where can i find the login page in wordpress and add my header to it

Tags: customization, wp-admin, login

Where can I find the wp-admin login file so i can add my header to it i can find it i looked in the wp-admin folder for `login.php` or anything like that but can not find it, i also tried looking in the `index.php` under wp-admin for it but still could not find it.

I want to add my site header to it, via `get_header();`.

i also tried going into `wp-login.php` and adding `get_header();` right under the `<body>` tag

Please help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Login Logo
To change the WordPress logo to your own, you will need to change the CSS styles associated with this heading:

```
<h1><a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress">Your Site Name</a></h1>
```

From https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form